# Push down optimization is throwing to the database unexpected querys (teradata)

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have a wokflow configured with "To Source Push Down Optimization". If I take a look to the Push Down optimization option (I edit the workflow task, Mapping tab, and select Pushdonw Optimization), I find that there are two push down groups, that's ok, it is what I expected.

Then I start the workflow, check the log and I see that PWC is not throwing this two querys to the database, instead five different querys are thrown to the database (not one per source, it is like a different push down grouping).

I 've checked the two querys that are suppossed to be launched to the database and they are correct.

Any ideas of what Am I doing wrong?

PD: I am using Teradata with PWC 9.1

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just found the way to know why Push Down Optimization is not working. In order to see why PDO stops, you have to take a look at the workflow log not the task log. I've found that a to_char(var) where var is a decimal port cannot be pushed to a Teradata database